# Symfony: update form fields after submitting the form

Tags: symfony

so pretty new to Symfony and on my way to learn. I am just struggling as follows:

In my controller class, I would like to update some input fields after submission. Code of function 'indexAction' is similar to the following:

```
public function indexAction (Request $request) {
$myentity = new TestEntity();
$myentity->setField1 ('value1');
$form = $this->createForm (TaskType::class,$myentity);
$form->handleRequest ($request);
if ($form->isValid())
  return $this->redirectToRoute ('nextPage');
else
  {
  // and here is my problem. I would like to set Field1 to 'value2',
  // but I cannot, as the form is already submitted. Or with the
  // following command directly setting the entity, the change is not
  // taken into account anymore.
  $myentity->setField1 ('value2');
  }
return $this->render ('test.html.twig', array (
  'form' => $form->createView());
}
```

Field1 is an input field that I would like to set to value1 if the form is called the first time. Once I press the "submit" button (and the form is NOT valid), the same form should show up, but then having set Field1 to value2.

Can't figure out, on how to achieve above. Any help appreciated.
Many thanks,
Wolfram

Comment: can you replace `$myentity->setField1 ('value2');` with `$form->get('field1')->setData('value');`

Comment: I did this before and got the message:
'You cannot change the data of a submitted form.'

Comment: I think this is because your form has already been bound to the entity. The form has taken the entity's data and is not updated when the entity changes. use `$form['field1']->setData( 'value2' );`

Comment: No, does not work. Same error as above.

Comment: then better to recreate your entire form in `else` part. `else
  {
   $myentity->setField1 ('value2');
   $form = $this->createForm (TaskType::class,$myentity);
  }`

Comment: This does not work either as Symfony does not let me create a form into a submitted form...

Comment: can you please add this thing in your form (`TaskType`) `$form...->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
 if(!$event->getForm()->isValid()){
  $event->getForm()->get('field1')->setData('value1');
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Add following thing in your form`TaskType.php`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    //YOUR CODE
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, 
         function (FormEvent $event) { 
           if(!$event->getForm()->isValid()){
             $event->getForm()->get('field1')->setData('value1'); 
           }
         });
```

Comment: well, it does not look to be in the right place here. I intended to modify my controller, not my form.
Nevertheless, I couldn't get this code running:
`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to AppBundle\Form\Type\TaskType::AppBundle\Form\Type\{closure}() must be an instance of AppBundle\Form\Type\FormEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent given`

Comment: can you please paster your `TaskType.php` here?

Comment: Is this working in newer versions?
I get this error on Symfony6

AlreadySubmittedException
HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
You cannot change the data of a submitted form.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm (FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
          ->add ('field1', TextType::class)
          ->add ('field2', TextType::class)
          ->add ('field3', TextType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions (OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults (array (
          'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task'
        ));
    }
}
```